# In yarn workspaces, can i import a submodule original ts file instead of "main": "lib/index.js" file？

Tags: typescript, yarnpkg, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

In my repo, i use yarn workspaces to manage multiple packages.The structure like:

```
packages
  pkg1
    lib
      index.js
    src
      index.ts
    package.json
  pkg2
    lib
      index.js
    src
      index.ts
    package.json
package.json
```

`lib` folder has the files output by `tsc`.
`package.json` in `pkg1`, `pkg2` has main field link to `lib` folder.e.g:

```
  "name": "...",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "license": "MIT"
```

In `pkg1`, i import some functions of `pkg2`.When i dev `pkg1` in local, i want to import ts file in src folder to dev quickly.Is there a way to achieve it?